# Simplexml parse XML with inline namespace

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How to parse a document like the one shown below?

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
<s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly'>
       <s:AttributeType name='StMovement' rs:number='1' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='number' rs:dbtype='numeric' dt:maxLength='19' rs:scale='0' rs:precision='28' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>

<rs:data>
<z:row StMovement='21123'/>
</rs:data>
```

I know that there is something like `.children(<schemaurl>)`, but this only works if there is an xsd at some URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [the `->children()` method](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php). Namespace identifiers do not have to point at an XSD in order to be used in this way, you just need to know the URI string to pass in.

You can also set the second parameter of that method to `true` and use the local alias/prefix for the namespace, which is theoretically less reliable, but usually fine in practice.

In your case (if you add the `</xml>`, which is missing in your sample above) both of the following will work fine:

```
echo (string)$sx->children('uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882')->Schema->attributes()->id;
echo (string)$sx->children('s', true)->Schema->attributes()->id;
```